# MySQL : Conditional ORDER BY to only one column

Tags: mysql, order-by, condition

Hello and thanks for taking time to read this question.

I am using MySQL, and I want to sort results using ORDER BY to one specific column, but the results must be ordered according an specific criteria to this column. For example, to the following table, I want to `ORDER BY 'group'`, showing first the `9,7,6 'group' items` and, in the end `10,8,5 'group' items`:

```
names     group
--------- ------
susanita  10
miguelito 5
mafalda   7
manolito  8
libertad  6
felipe    9
guille    8
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: This was a good puzzle. I am sure many have dealt with situation. So, +1 for bringing it to the table today !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT* FROM mytable ORDER BY
LOCATE(CONCAT('.',`group`,'.'),'.9.7.6.10.8.5.');
```

I took your sample data, loaded it into a table called mytable and ran it.

Here are the results:

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> drop table if exists mytable;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> create table mytable
    -> (
    ->    names varchar(10),
    ->    `group` int
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable values
    -> ('susanita',  10),
    -> ('miguelito', 5),
    -> ('mafalda',   7),
    -> ('manolito',  8),
    -> ('libertad',  6),
    -> ('felipe',    9),
    -> ('guille',    8);
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.09 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM mytable;
+-----------+-------+
| names     | group |
+-----------+-------+
| susanita  |    10 |
| miguelito |     5 |
| mafalda   |     7 |
| manolito  |     8 |
| libertad  |     6 |
| felipe    |     9 |
| guille    |     8 |
+-----------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY
    -> LOCATE(CONCAT('.',`group`,'.'),'.9.7.6.10.8.5.');
+-----------+-------+
| names     | group |
+-----------+-------+
| felipe    |     9 |
| mafalda   |     7 |
| libertad  |     6 |
| susanita  |    10 |
| manolito  |     8 |
| guille    |     8 |
| miguelito |     5 |
+-----------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

**UPDATE 2011-09-06 12:33 EDT**

Here is another approach:

```
SELECT* FROM mytable ORDER BY
IF(FIELD(`group`,9,7,6,10,8,5)=0,99999,FIELD(`group`,9,7,6,10,8,5));
```

This will force any groups other than 9,7,6,10,8,5 to appear at the very bottom of the query.

**UPDATE 2011-09-06 14:39 EDT**

```
mysql> SELECT names, `group`
    -> FROM mytable
    -> WHERE `group` IN (9,7,6,10,8,5)
    -> ORDER BY find_in_set(`group`,'9,7,6,10,8,5');
+-----------+-------+
| names     | group |
+-----------+-------+
| felipe    |     9 |
| mafalda   |     7 |
| libertad  |     6 |
| susanita  |    10 |
| manolito  |     8 |
| guille    |     8 |
| miguelito |     5 |
+-----------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hey @Nick, yours works as well against my sample data !!!

Comment: Hello Rolando, thanks for your answer, it works for me if the data type of 'group' is 'int' or 'varchar', and if the group have similar text (for example text9, text7, text6, text10, text8, text5). thankyou! powerfull approach.

Comment: Nice job, Rolando! +1

Comment: I guess `field()` and `find_in_set()` are nearly identical.  I've used the latter in the past.

Answer (score 5):

Use MySQL's [`find_in_set()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function to do this.  It is more concise but less portable than the [CASE approach](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5422/mysql-conditional-order-by-to-only-one-column/5430#5430) gbn proposed.

[For example](http://www.stevemckeogh.co.uk/blog/2010/1/order-mysql-results-in-a-predefined-set-list-order/):

```
SELECT `names`, `group`
FROM my_table
WHERE `group` IN (9,7,6,10,8,5)
ORDER BY find_in_set(`group`,'9,7,6,10,8,5');
```

Because it relies on string searching, `find_in_set()` is useful mainly for ordering on small sets of easily searchable keys, like integers.

Comment: I tested this against my sample data. It works. I just added backquotes around group since group is a reserved word for GROUP BY. Otherwise, +1 for your use of find_in_set !!!

Comment: @Rolando - Updated my answer to add those back ticks around `group`.

Answer (score 3):

Typically (it's asked daily in SO) you'd use a CASE which is standard SQL

```
ORDER BY
    CASE group
          WHEN 9 THEN 1
          WHEN 7 THEN 2
          WHEN 6 THEN 3
          WHEN 10 THEN 4
          WHEN 8 THEN 5
          WHEN 5 THEN 6
          ELSE 7
    END
```

I'd be interested to see how this compares over a large dataset to the LOCATE(CONCAT...) method from RolandoMySQLDBA

For a more complex example, see ['Conversion failed' error with ORDER BY CASE expression](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/4162/630)

Comment: Kudos for a simpler approach. String manipulation could be costly. My answer was just quick-and-dirty. Your answer is strictly numerical. +1 !!!

Comment: You inspired me to come up with another solution. It is quasi-numerical but still functional.

Answer (score 2):

You could create it as an [ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html) type.

> ENUM values are sorted according to the order in which the enumeration members were listed in the column specification. (In other words, ENUM values are sorted according to their index numbers.) For example, 'a' sorts before 'b' for ENUM('a', 'b'), but 'b' sorts before 'a' for ENUM('b', 'a').

So create the ENUM field as `ENUM('9','7','6','10','8','5')`

Disclaimer: I do not endorse this, because I suspect that your `group` column needs to be dynamic. I am just mentioning it as an option.

Comment: hi DTest, I agree, like you say is useful alternative if the values in the column will not change. thankyou!

Comment: @DTest - Hey that's slick !!! I never thought about ENUMs in that respect. + 1 !!!