# CASE ORDER BY with multiple columns, and different sort options

Tags: stored-procedures, t-sql, order-by, case

I am attempting to use a T-SQL `CASE ORDER BY` in a stored procedure where I am passed @OrderBy parameter as a TINYINT.

- `@Orderby = 1 Then Date column should be ASC`
- `@Orderby = 2 Then Date column should be DESC`

My question is: How can I get the date column to sort desc when I am passed a 2 for that parameter, and have the a string column sort asc in the same CASE ORDER BY statement?

This is what I have now for the `CASE ORDER BY`

```
    ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 1 THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30) , ccd.CertEndDate) + tp.LastName + tp.FirstName END ,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 2 THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30) , ccd.CertEndDate) + tp.LastName + tp.FirstName END DESC
```

This codes parses and returns a result set without error, but the 2nd CASE ORDER BY is all in DESC sort order, when I would prefer to have ccd.CertEndDate DESC , tp.LastName ASC , tp.FirstName ASC

Thanks in advance.

Comment: here is my one maybe help http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7301/how-to-make-conditional-ordering-for-two-or-more-columns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Break it out a little more:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @orderby = 1 THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30) , ccd.CertEndDate) END ASC,
         CASE WHEN @orderby = 2 THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30) , ccd.CertEndDate) END DESC,
         tp.lastname ASC,
         tp.firstname ASC
```

You only need the sort order to change on the first field, so don't enclose the others in the `CASE`.

It should be noted that we don't include an `ELSE` for each `CASE`, which means any other value will return `NULL` and be discarded from the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thank you, yes that was it.  The developer passing me the parameter value is only passing a 1 or 2, but I may wrap some error handling around it just in case.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Along with JNK's answer, you could also consider:

```
DECLARE @Example TABLE
(
    first_name      NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name       NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    cert_end_date   DATE NOT NULL,
    other_columns   NCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT (N'')

    UNIQUE (cert_end_date ASC, first_name, last_name),
    UNIQUE (cert_end_date DESC, first_name, last_name)
)

INSERT @Example
    (first_name, last_name, cert_end_date)
VALUES
    ('a', 'w', '2008-12-31'),
    ('b', 'x', '2009-12-31'),
    ('c', 'y', '2010-12-31'),
    ('d', 'z', '2011-12-31')

DECLARE
    @order_date_ascending BIT = CONVERT(BIT, 'true')

-- 1.  May require an explicit sort despite useful indexes
SELECT
    e.first_name,
    e.last_name,
    e.cert_end_date
FROM @Example AS e
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @order_date_ascending = 1 THEN e.cert_end_date END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @order_date_ascending = 0 THEN e.cert_end_date END DESC,
    e.first_name ASC,
    e.last_name ASC

-- 2.  Conditional statements
IF  @order_date_ascending = CONVERT(BIT, 'true')
BEGIN
    SELECT
        e.first_name,
        e.last_name,
        e.cert_end_date
    FROM @Example AS e
    ORDER BY
        e.cert_end_date ASC,
        e.first_name ASC,
        e.last_name ASC
END
ELSE IF @order_date_ascending = CONVERT(BIT, 'false')
BEGIN
    SELECT
        e.first_name,
        e.last_name,
        e.cert_end_date
    FROM @Example AS e
    ORDER BY
        e.cert_end_date DESC,
        e.first_name ASC,
        e.last_name ASC
END

-- 3.  Union All & Start-up Filters
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP (9223372036854775807)
        e.first_name,
        e.last_name,
        e.cert_end_date
    FROM @Example AS e
    WHERE
        @order_date_ascending = CONVERT(BIT, 'true')
    ORDER BY
        e.cert_end_date ASC,
        e.first_name ASC,
        e.last_name ASC
) AS sort_asc
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP (9223372036854775807)
        e.first_name,
        e.last_name,
        e.cert_end_date
    FROM @Example AS e
    WHERE
        @order_date_ascending = CONVERT(BIT, 'false')
    ORDER BY
        e.cert_end_date DESC,
        e.first_name ASC,
        e.last_name ASC
) AS sort_desc
```

The first and third methods can benefit from the Parameter Embedding Optimization available on SQL Server 2008 SP1 CU5 if a statement-level compilation occurs, or is forced to occur using the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` query hint.  See this [MSDN blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/grahamk/changed-behaviour-of-option-recompile-syntax-in-sql-server-2008-sp1-cumulative-update-5) entry for details.

The third method does not require a compilation each time, since the Filter operators in the plan have a Start-Up Expression.  The plan sub-tree below each Filter is only executed if the condition evaluates to true.