# Using 2 order by in procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to use 2 `order by` in my procedure.

When I use only the second `order by` is working and not the first one.

What mistake am I doing?

Here is my procedure

```
BEGIN

SELECT 
    sd.ShopID,
    @dist:= ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(lat) ) * cos( radians( sd.Lat ) ) * cos( radians( sd.Lng ) - radians(lng) ) + sin( radians(lat) ) * sin( radians( sd.Lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
    FROM 
        shop_details sd 
    WHERE 
        sd.Status = '1' 
    Order by 
        sd.Status Asc,
        distance Asc;
    END
```

(Don't care about the @dist formulae, as it will return the distance)

In the end I want to display the `status` as Ascending and `distance` as Ascending.

While I use

```
Order by 
    sd.Status Asc,
    distance Asc
```

I got only `distance` as Asc and I got the `sd.Status` is not in ordered. I tried it vice versa but I got the same issue.

How can I do this without using a separate table like in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)?

I tried [this way](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9109/case-order-by-with-multiple-columns-and-different-sort-options).

Comment: Sulthan, it's best to limit your code samples to the minimum that will demonstrate the problem you would like help with.  Please edit your question and remove the parts of the query which are not needed.

Comment: @Michael Green Yes i have updated my question.

Comment: Show some sample data,I suspect a misunderstanding of how ORDER BY works.

Comment: Your query filters on `sd.Status = '1'`, so ordering on that column is pretty useless... there's only one value. If you still have this issue, please update your question is a realistic query and sample data (and output).

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `ORDER BY` is correct. However, You need to know that it has to go in order by how you specified! So your query will first order `sd.Status` FIRST, then it will order by `distance` SECOND.

For example This is how you're expecting it to look (Just my random data I gave)

```
 sd.Status   distance
 ---------   --------
     A         231
     A         245
     A         657
     A         987
     B         123
     B         432
     D         465
     D         576
     S         555
```

Note how it is ORDERED.